# Georeferenced raster not even generated in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am trying to superimpose an old map on top of a Google Satellite image, but for some reason, the raster layer won't be generated with Georeferencer and be shown in the layers window even when the system says that `Raster was successfully georeferenced`. I confirmed that the CRS (EPSG:3857) are matching and everything looks good to me.

How can I go about this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You haven't checked "Load in QGIS when done". It looks like the output raster is saved to your desktop. Do you find it there?

Comment: Oh boy I did not indeed! It works now, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Great! No problem :-)

Comment: @Ben W please add your comment as an answer